# C# Madbee Managed Android Debug Bridge

Tags: c#

I would like to use this managed adb wrapper: https://madb.codeplex.com/
I installed with Install-Package Managed.Adb.x64

I get a exception and I dont know how to handle with it

My Consolenapp looks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Managed.Adb;
using System.IO;

namespace ADBManaged
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AndroidDebugBridge bridge = AndroidDebugBridge.CreateBridge(@"D:\ADB\ADB.exe", true);
            bridge.Start();
            GetDevices();
        }

        private static void GetDevices()
        {
            foreach (var device in AdbHelper.Instance.GetDevices(AndroidDebugBridge.SocketAddress))
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", device.SerialNumber, device.State);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Exception

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'MoreLinq,
Version=1.1.17511.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=384d532d7e88985d'
or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does
not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I checked the references and MoreLinq is installed, but seems with different version v2.0.50727.

Should I downgrade or what can I do ?

Comment: Problem solved: I had to update MorelInq by hand via Nuget PackageManager

Comment: Still getting some Exceptions A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Managed.Adb.dll I dont know the real reason for this, but seems still working

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to upgrade morelinq from 1.0.0 to 1.4.0, after that it worked fine. Also you cannot upgrade to anything above because it't not compatible with the current version of Managed.Adb(2.0.131.13916).